# J'accule / j'éjacule ?

Tags: littérature

Bonjour,

> Frères de ma chair je vous adore ! Amour de mes veilles, hourra !
> **J'accule au zénith Caïn ! gicle panaris !** Triomphe ! je te vois ! Pro
> Deo !

Savez-vous ce que signifie le passage ***J'accule au zénith Caïn ! gicle panaris !*** ? Y a-t-il ici un travail sur l'ambiguité et l'érotisme à partir du signifiant (*j'accule* / *j'éjacule*) ?

Answer (score 1):

Bien que cet écrivain n'hésite pas à se vautrer dans la boue, il ne faut pas penser que ce soit chez lui systématique. Il est plus probable dans le cas présent qu'il joue sur l'expression « être au zénith », c'est à dire « être au point le plus haut dans le domaine que l'on considère » (succès professionnel, influence politique, gloire, etc.). Il forcerait donc Caïn (il l'accule), l'archétype du mal, au pire niveau de malfaisance que l'on puisse lui imputer, ou plutôt il est prêt à le considérer à un tel niveau dans la suite de son récit.

En lisant ce qui précède et ce qui suit cette référence à Caïn, il devient clair que le narrateur vitupère contre ses contemporains, leur crache littéralement sa haine à la figure, lui, qui apparemment leur veut tant de bien, mais qui est traité par eux comme  un  Caïn a traité son frère Abel. Il est apparemment en proie à une visualisation confuse des conséquences de son existences, à une anxiété concernant sa vie à venir, qu'il sent menacée par ses contemporains, lesquels lui reprochent apparemment, et entre autres choses, ses livres : « ils m'arrivent en fossoyeurs […] Tout m'est parti d'un bord à l'autre, de vive force, à la douceur. preuve passe et peau* Cachot pour finir […] Les gens m'ont traité pas très bien. […] mes livres pour ça. […] Si je lui donnais un fort marteau là au môme, lui proposais de me fendre la tronche ? à moi-même, là tout de suite, céans ? Il oserait pas !…Il canerait. D'autres viendront, emporteront d assaut le local la bibliothèque. ».

Cela continue par un lynchage, le narrateur en faisant les frais, puis de nouveau des allusions de pillage en tout genre dont il est encore la victime. Un peu  plus loin on trouve « Confusion des lieux, des temps Merde C'est la féerie vous comprenez. Féerie c'est ça. l'avenir! Passé! Faux Vrai! ».  C'est là que l'on peut soupsonner plus fortement qu'il est lui-même Caïn, d'où la possible double interprétation qu'il se fait l'image la plus ignoble de son prochain et de lui-même tout aussi bien.

Daans cette optique, l'idée d'une comparaison du phallus et du sperme à un abcès et son pus ne semble pas intéressante, mais sait-on jamais.

Comment: Merci pour votre avis !